# Controller getting NULL value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a call to a controller via jQuery $.post, but the parameter for my controller method keeps getting a NULL value despite it appearing to be setup similar to other controller methods.

#### CONTROLLER

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SearchWeatherLocations(string searchFor)
{
    //Do Some Magic
}
```

#### GLOBAL.ASAX

```
routes.MapRoute("SearchWeatherLocations", "Home/SearchWeatherLocations/{searchFor}",
new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "SearchWeatherLocations"
});
```

#### jQuery Call From View

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetWeatherLocations("seat");
    });
    function GetWeatherLocations(sSearchFor) {
        var divToBeWorkedOn = '#locations';
        var webMethod = '<%= Url.Action("SearchWeatherLocations", "Home") %>/';
        var url = webMethod + sSearchFor;
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            $('#locations').children().remove();
            for (var count in data) {
                $('#locations').append("<li>" + data[count].LocationName + "&nbsp;(" + data[count].LocationCode + ")</li>");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your post like this;

jQuery

```
$.post("/Articles/jQueryAddComment", { commentText: commentText, id: id, type: commentType }, function(newCommentListHTML) 
{
});
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult jQueryAddComment(string commentText, int id, string type)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm feeling rather nooby all of a sudden!